# Using a constructor for return

Tags: c++, return-value, constructor

Just a quick question.

I've written some code that returns a custom class Command, and the code I've written seems to work fine. I was wondering if there are any reasons that I shouldn't be doing it this way. It's something like this:

```
Command Behavior::getCommand ()
{
  char input = 'x';

  return Command (input, -1, -1);
}
```

Anyway, I read that constructors aren't meant to have a return value, but this works in g++.

Thanks for any advice,

Rhys

Comment: It should be noted: This, semantically, creates a temporary object then copies it as the function returns. However, compilers are allowed to perform what's called return-value optimization, or RVO. This means it's allowed to not do a copy, for example: `Command x = getCommand();` will directly construct `x`, instead of making `x` a copy of whatever was returned.

Comment: Long story short: You are doing everything right!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor itself doesn't have a return value.  What this does is constructs a temporary `Command` object and returns the constructed objet to the caller.  It's effectively the same as if you said:

```
Command temp(input, -1, -1);
return temp;
```

It will work on any C++ compiler.

Comment: Thanks for that! Glad I don't have to rewrite it, it's nice functionality.

Answer (score 2):

`getCommand` isn't a constructor. The above is perfectly valid, and also generally efficient, due to thre return-value optimisation (RVO), which (I think) wouldn't apply if you instantiated a local variable and returned that.

Comment: Under many circumstances, local variables can be retured sans-copy constructor as well.

Comment: Which is called Named Return Value Optimization, or NRVO.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. I wasn't aware of NRVO.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor doesn't have a return value; you're explicitly constructing a temporary instance of the class, and returning that.  There's nothing wrong with this, other than it will make a copy.

If you want to avoid the copy, you have a few options, one of which is to have an out parameter which is a `Command*` and use new and delete.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a constructor with a return value. 
`Command::Command(char, int, int)` is your constructor.

You have a method which returns an object, which is perfectly normal.